# S Memo home screen shortcut

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, home-screen-shortcuts, s-memo

How can I add a S Memo note as a home screen shortcut? When I first got my Samsung Galaxy S3 there was a shortcut which I deleted.This was not  a shortcut for the app but for a saved note.Now I can't find a way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Widgets" folder, there should be an S Memo widget in it. Push and hold it. It will give you an option to move a generic S Memo note onto one of your home screens. Once you've done that, you can open it and choose between making this shortcut an existing note and creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you find S memo in application menu?

if Yes then long press on S Memo and add to home screen.

if No then Download from [HERE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.widgetapp.diotek.smemo) and do above step

Also search in widget